Can not evaluate nested operations using Xquery
Below is my Xquery code. Focus on calculateExpression
import schema namespace uli = "http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~sattler/" at "examSchema.xsd";
declare variable $examFile as xs:string external;
declare function local:markAB($answers as element()+, $questions as element()*) as element() {
    <result>
        <total-mark>{
            sum(
                for $answer in $answers
                let $question := $questions[@id = $answer/@QuestionID]
                let $correctValue := local:calculateExpression($question/uli:Expression)
                let $answerValue := string($answer/@Value)
                let $isCorrect := 
                    if ($answerValue = "Not Answered") then 
                        false()
                    else if ($answerValue castable as xs:decimal and $correctValue instance of xs:decimal) then
                        xs:decimal($answerValue) = $correctValue
                    else 
                        $answerValue = string($correctValue)
                return
                    if ($isCorrect) then
                        if (exists($question/@marks)) then xs:decimal($question/@marks) else 1
                    else 
                        0
            )
        }</total-mark>
        <debug>{
            for $answer in $answers
            let $question := $questions[@id = $answer/@QuestionID]
            let $correctValue := local:calculateExpression($question/uli:Expression)
            let $answerValue := string($answer/@Value)
            let $isCorrect := 
                if ($answerValue = "Not Answered") then 
                    false()
                else if ($answerValue castable as xs:decimal and $correctValue instance of xs:decimal) then
                    xs:decimal($answerValue) = $correctValue
                else 
                    $answerValue = string($correctValue)
            return
                <answer-debug>
                    <questionID>{$answer/@QuestionID}</questionID>
                    <answerValue>{$answerValue}</answerValue>
                    <correctValue>{$correctValue}</correctValue>
                    <answerType>{
                        if ($answerValue castable as xs:decimal) then "decimal"
                        else "string"
                    }</answerType>
                    <correctValueType>{
                        if ($correctValue instance of xs:decimal) then "decimal"
                        else "string"
                    }</correctValueType>
                    <comparisonResult>{
                        if ($answerValue = "Not Answered") then "Not Answered"
                        else if ($isCorrect) then "Correct"
                        else "Incorrect"
                    }</comparisonResult>
                    <marks>{
                        if ($isCorrect) then
                            if (exists($question/@marks)) then $question/@marks else 1
                        else 
                            0
                    }</marks>
                </answer-debug>
        }</debug>
    </result>
};
declare function local:calculateExpression($expression as element()) as xs:decimal {
    let $result :=
        if ($expression/uli:times) then
            fold-left($expression/uli:times/*/@value, 1, 
                function($acc, $val) { $acc * xs:decimal($val) })
        else if ($expression/uli:plus) then
            sum(for $num in $expression/uli:plus/*/@value return xs:decimal($num))
        else if ($expression/uli:minus) then
            if (count($expression/uli:minus/*) = 2) then
                xs:decimal($expression/uli:minus[1]/@value) - xs:decimal($expression/uli:minus[2]/@value)
            else
                0 (: Default value if there aren't exactly two operands :)
        else if ($expression/uli:int) then
            xs:decimal($expression/uli:int/@value)
        else if ($expression/uli:dec) then
            xs:decimal($expression/uli:dec/@value)
        else
            0 (: Default value if no recognized operation is found :)
    return
        if (empty($result)) then 0 else $result
};

declare function local:answerBookRow($ab as element(uli:AnswerBook), $passP as xs:decimal, $totalMarks as xs:decimal, $questions as element()*) as element()+ {
    let $markResult := local:markAB($ab/uli:Answer, $questions)
    let $rawMark := $markResult/total-mark
    let $percentage := round(($rawMark div $totalMarks) * 100)
    let $status := if ($percentage >= $passP) then "Pass" else "Fail"
    return
        (
        <tr>
            <td>{$ab/@studentID/string()}</td>
            <td>{$rawMark}</td>
            <td>{concat($percentage, "%")}</td>
            <td>{$status}</td>
        </tr>,
        <debug>
            <studentID>{$ab/@studentID/string()}</studentID>
            <rawMark>{$rawMark}</rawMark>
            <percentage>{$percentage}</percentage>
            <status>{$status}</status>
            <answers>{$markResult/debug/*}</answers>
        </debug>
        )
};

declare function local:examResultsTable($exam, $passP, $totalMarks) {
    (
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>StudentID</th>
            <th>Raw Mark</th>
            <th>Percentage Mark</th>
            <th>Pass/Fail?</th>
        </tr>
        {
            for $AB in $exam//uli:AnswerBook
            return local:answerBookRow($AB, $passP, $totalMarks, $exam/uli:Questions/uli:Question)[1]
        }
    </table>,
    <debug>
    {
        for $AB in $exam//uli:AnswerBook
        return local:answerBookRow($AB, $passP, $totalMarks, $exam/uli:Questions/uli:Question)[2]
    }
    </debug>
    )
};

declare function local:examResults($exam) {
    let $totalMarks := sum($exam/uli:Questions/uli:Question/@marks)
    let $passP := xs:decimal($exam/@PercentageToPass)
    return
        <results>
            <p>
                The total number of marks achievable is {$totalMarks} and you need
                {$passP}% of these to pass the exam.
                {local:examResultsTable($exam, $passP, $totalMarks)[1]}
            </p>
            {local:examResultsTable($exam, $passP, $totalMarks)[2]}
        </results>
};

declare function local:examReport($exam) {
    let $results := local:examResults($exam)
    return
     <html>
        <head>
            <title>Exam Report</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Exam for {$exam/@CourseCode/string()} for the year {$exam/@Year/string()}</h1>
            <h2>Exam results</h2>
            {$results/*[not(self::debug)]}
            <h2>Debug Information</h2>
            {$results/debug}
        </body>
    </html>
};

let $exam := (validate {doc($examFile)})/element(uli:Exam)
return local:examReport($exam)

The xml file is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Exam CourseCode="Math101" Year="2022" PercentageToPass="50"
    xmlns="http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~sattler/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~sattler/ examSchema.xsd">
    <AnswerBooks>
        <AnswerBook studentID="S12344">
            <Answer QuestionID="Q1" Value="Not Answered"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q2" Value="Not Answered"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q3" Value="Not Answered"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q4" Value="Not Answered"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q5" Value="Not Answered"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q6" Value="Not Answered"/>
        </AnswerBook>
        <AnswerBook studentID="S12345">
            <Answer QuestionID="Q1" Value="1000"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q2" Value="100"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q3" Value="5"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q4" Value="2"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q5" Value="Not Answered"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q6" Value="Not Answered"/>
        </AnswerBook>
        <AnswerBook studentID="s12346">
            <Answer QuestionID="Q1" Value="Not Answered"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q4" Value="2"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q2" Value="7.5"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q3" Value="7"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q5" Value="Not Answered"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q6" Value="Not Answered"/>
        </AnswerBook>
        <AnswerBook studentID="s12348">
            <Answer QuestionID="Q1" Value="32"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q2" Value="7.5"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q3" Value="19"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q4" Value="2"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q5" Value="1"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q6" Value="16"/>
        </AnswerBook>
        <AnswerBook studentID="S12347">
            <Answer QuestionID="Q1" Value="32"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q2" Value="7"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q3" Value="19"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q4" Value="2"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q5" Value="1"/>
            <Answer QuestionID="Q6" Value="15"/>
        </AnswerBook>
    </AnswerBooks>
    <Questions>
        <Question id="Q1" marks="3" level="3">
            <Expression>
                <description/>
                <times>
                    <int value="2"/>
                    <int value="2"/>
                    <int value="2"/>
                    <int value="2"/>
                    <int value="2"/>
                </times>
            </Expression>
            <Feedback answerCorrect="t">This was a really difficult question because it was very
                long: well done!</Feedback>
            <Feedback answerCorrect="f">This was a really difficult question because it was very
                long - check your working again</Feedback>
        </Question>
        <Question id="Q2" marks="2" level="3">
            <Expression>
                <description/>
                <times>
                    <dec value="2.5"/>
                    <dec value="3"/>
                </times>
            </Expression>
    
            <Feedback answerCorrect="t">This was a really difficult question: well done!</Feedback>
            <Feedback answerCorrect="f">This was a really difficult question - check your working
                again and your understanding of decimal numbers.</Feedback>
        </Question>
        <Question id="Q3" level="2" marks="2">
            <Expression>
                <description/>
                <plus>
                    <int value="4"/>
                    <int value="3"/>
                    <times>
                        <int value="4"/>
                        <int value="3"/>
                    </times>
                </plus>
            </Expression>

            <Feedback answerCorrect="t">Well done!</Feedback>
            <Feedback answerCorrect="f">Check your working again and your understanding of
                nesting.</Feedback>
        </Question>
        <Question id="Q4" level="1">
            <Expression>
                <description/>
                <plus>
                    <int value="1"/>
                    <int value="1"/>
                </plus>
            </Expression>
            <Feedback answerCorrect="t">Well done!</Feedback>
            <Feedback answerCorrect="f">Please pay more attention next time.</Feedback>
        </Question>
        <Question id="Q5" level="1">
            <Expression>
                <description/>
                <int value="1"/>
            </Expression>
 
            <Feedback answerCorrect="t">Well done!</Feedback>
            <Feedback answerCorrect="f">Please pay more attention next time.</Feedback>
        </Question>
        <Question id="Q6" level="2" marks="4">
        <Expression>
            <description/>
            <minus>
                <plus>
                    <int value="2"/>
                    <int value="3"/>
                    <times>
                        <int value="5"/>
                        <minus>
                            <int value="6"/>
                            <int value="3"/>
                        </minus>
                    </times>
                </plus>
                <int value="4"/>
            </minus>
        </Expression>
        
        <Feedback answerCorrect="t">Well done!</Feedback>
        <Feedback answerCorrect="f">Please pay more attention next time.</Feedback>
    </Question>
    </Questions>
</Exam>

My task is to check the answers and say whether they are correct or not.
I am calculating everything fine except Q6. What am I doing wrong?
Below is my output HTML
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Exam Report</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Exam for Math101 for the year 2022</h1>
        <h2>Exam results</h2>
        <p>
            The total number of marks achievable is 13 and you need
            50% of these to pass the exam.
            
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>StudentID</th>
                    <th>Raw Mark</th>
                    <th>Percentage Mark</th>
                    <th>Pass/Fail?</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>S12344</td>
                    <td>
                        <total-mark>0</total-mark>
                    </td>
                    <td>0%</td>
                    <td>Fail</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>S12345</td>
                    <td>
                        <total-mark>1</total-mark>
                    </td>
                    <td>8%</td>
                    <td>Fail</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>s12346</td>
                    <td>
                        <total-mark>5</total-mark>
                    </td>
                    <td>38%</td>
                    <td>Fail</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>s12348</td>
                    <td>
                        <total-mark>7</total-mark>
                    </td>
                    <td>54%</td>
                    <td>Pass</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>S12347</td>
                    <td>
                        <total-mark>5</total-mark>
                    </td>
                    <td>38%</td>
                    <td>Fail</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </p>
        <h2>Debug Information</h2>
        <debug>
            <debug>
                <studentID>S12344</studentID>
                <rawMark>
                    <total-mark>0</total-mark>
                </rawMark>
                <percentage>0</percentage>
                <status>Fail</status>
                <answers>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q1"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>Not Answered</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>32</correctValue>
                        <answerType>string</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Not Answered</comparisonResult>
                        <marks>0</marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q2"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>Not Answered</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>7.5</correctValue>
                        <answerType>string</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Not Answered</comparisonResult>
                        <marks>0</marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q3"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>Not Answered</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>7</correctValue>
                        <answerType>string</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Not Answered</comparisonResult>
                        <marks>0</marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q4"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>Not Answered</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>2</correctValue>
                        <answerType>string</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Not Answered</comparisonResult>
                        <marks>0</marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q5"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>Not Answered</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>1</correctValue>
                        <answerType>string</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Not Answered</comparisonResult>
                        <marks>0</marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q6"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>Not Answered</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>0</correctValue>
                        <answerType>string</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Not Answered</comparisonResult>
                        <marks>0</marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                </answers>
            </debug>
            <debug>
                <studentID>S12345</studentID>
                <rawMark>
                    <total-mark>1</total-mark>
                </rawMark>
                <percentage>8</percentage>
                <status>Fail</status>
                <answers>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q1"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>1000</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>32</correctValue>
                        <answerType>decimal</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Incorrect</comparisonResult>
                        <marks>0</marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q2"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>100</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>7.5</correctValue>
                        <answerType>decimal</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Incorrect</comparisonResult>
                        <marks>0</marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q3"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>5</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>7</correctValue>
                        <answerType>decimal</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Incorrect</comparisonResult>
                        <marks>0</marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q4"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>2</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>2</correctValue>
                        <answerType>decimal</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Correct</comparisonResult>
                        <marks marks="1"></marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q5"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>Not Answered</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>1</correctValue>
                        <answerType>string</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Not Answered</comparisonResult>
                        <marks>0</marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q6"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>Not Answered</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>0</correctValue>
                        <answerType>string</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Not Answered</comparisonResult>
                        <marks>0</marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                </answers>
            </debug>
            <debug>
                <studentID>s12346</studentID>
                <rawMark>
                    <total-mark>5</total-mark>
                </rawMark>
                <percentage>38</percentage>
                <status>Fail</status>
                <answers>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q1"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>Not Answered</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>32</correctValue>
                        <answerType>string</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Not Answered</comparisonResult>
                        <marks>0</marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q4"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>2</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>2</correctValue>
                        <answerType>decimal</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Correct</comparisonResult>
                        <marks marks="1"></marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q2"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>7.5</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>7.5</correctValue>
                        <answerType>decimal</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Correct</comparisonResult>
                        <marks marks="2"></marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q3"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>7</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>7</correctValue>
                        <answerType>decimal</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Correct</comparisonResult>
                        <marks marks="2"></marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q5"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>Not Answered</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>1</correctValue>
                        <answerType>string</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Not Answered</comparisonResult>
                        <marks>0</marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q6"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>Not Answered</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>0</correctValue>
                        <answerType>string</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Not Answered</comparisonResult>
                        <marks>0</marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                </answers>
            </debug>
            <debug>
                <studentID>s12348</studentID>
                <rawMark>
                    <total-mark>7</total-mark>
                </rawMark>
                <percentage>54</percentage>
                <status>Pass</status>
                <answers>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q1"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>32</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>32</correctValue>
                        <answerType>decimal</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Correct</comparisonResult>
                        <marks marks="3"></marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q2"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>7.5</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>7.5</correctValue>
                        <answerType>decimal</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Correct</comparisonResult>
                        <marks marks="2"></marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q3"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>19</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>7</correctValue>
                        <answerType>decimal</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Incorrect</comparisonResult>
                        <marks>0</marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q4"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>2</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>2</correctValue>
                        <answerType>decimal</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Correct</comparisonResult>
                        <marks marks="1"></marks>
                    </answer-debug>
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q5"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>1</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>1</correctValue>
                        <answerType>decimal</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Correct</comparisonResult>
                        <marks marks="1"></marks>
                    </answer-debug>
 

I was expecting it to evaluate the answers and check them to see if they are correct. everything is correct except for question 6. Please help me with this

If everything is working except one small part, try to cut down the example so it only deals with that part, so that we don't have to spend so much time finding our way through lots of working code. Isolating the failing part in this way may even make the answer obvious,
The thing that strikes me as odd about your code is that the Expression element clearly has a recursive structure involving nested subexpressions, but your calculateExpression function doesn't appear to be recursive, which one would expect for code following the interpreter design pattern.
